# Enumerating properties and values using forEach

Tags: javascript

Below code does not enumerate the properties & values of `Array` constructor on a web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            window.onload = myfunc;
            function myfunc(){
                window['Object']['getOwnPropertyNames'] (window['Array'])['forEach'](function(val){
                    document.write(val + ": " + Array[val] + "<br />" );
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any issue with the argument passed to `forEach`?

Comment: Any reason why you use `window['Object']` etc. instead of `Object`?

Comment: The `forEach` is fine.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqc3ve3/)

Comment: And `['getOwnPropertyNames']`rather than `.getOwnPropertyNames` and likewise for `forEach`?

Comment: @Arg0n Because `window` object is dictionaries of dictionaries. I want to resemble that in code. I know this is less readable, but I want to see my mistakes in writing such syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the argument is fine, you have an extra `}` closing bracket.

```
window.onload = myfunc;
            function myfunc(){
                var x = "";
                window['Object']['getOwnPropertyNames'] (window['Array'])['forEach'](function(val){
                    x += val + ": " + Array[val] + "<br />" ;
                });
                document.write(x);
            }
```

I hope that you know `document.write` will replace the whole document. Moreover i have appended whatever you want to print in a variable `x`, you can use this `x` to display the output.

Answer (score 1):

using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array);` would be better

but if want to insist on you method then :

```
 window['Object']['getOwnPropertyNames'] (window['Array'])['forEach'](function(val){
                  console.log(val);
                });
```

you had an extra `}`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an extra closing curly brace in your code, which you can see easier when you fix the indentation of your code:

   ```
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. You can use window objects directly, there is no need for `window['propertyName']`.

   ```
   window['Object']['getOwnPropertyNames'](...)
   // is the same as
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(...)
   ```
3. You may want to use `.forEach` to call a method on returned results, not `['forEach']`:

   ```
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(function (propName) {
       console.log('In global window scope: ', propName);
   });
   ```